# VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_TOO_MANY_LISTS_IN_TRACK error in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

Couldn't find any info in the GP console or by general internet search, maybe someone has encountered this problem already.

After upgrading the target SDK levels to 29 an error started to show up when trying to review the new test build in Closed beta branch.

VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_TOO_MANY_LISTS_IN_TRACK
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4gCz.png

If anyone has encountered this already, would be glad for advice on how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error is displayed if there are too many e-mail lists for testers. You can remove the ones you don't need now, Google Play Console did not have this possibility before.
Once removed, the new build could be submitted to the closed test branch, so that solved the issue.